# Apply Styles to Dynamically loaded Components from the parent Component in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

In Angular (v6) I'm trying to dynamically load some components, and the component is been inserted successfully.

The problem that I'm facing, is that the component dynamically loaded, doesn't have the styles that the main component give him.

Basically i want that all components ***app-stuff*** on the parent component ***app-root*** to have 5px of margin.

Is there any way to achieve this?

My code looks like this :

Main component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { StuffComponent } from './StuffComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div class="componentList"><ng-container #testOutlet ></ng-container></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('replaceDiv', { read: ViewContainerRef }) replaceDiv: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.loadComponent(), 1000);
  }

  loadComponent() {
    const ref = this.replaceDiv.createComponent(StuffComponent);
  }

}
```

Style for the main Component:

```
.componentList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

app-stuff
{
    margin:5px;
}
```

Component to be inserted :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stuff',
  template: '<p></p>',
  styleUrls: ['./stuff.component.scss'],
})
export class StuffComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  print() {
    console.log('### stuff ###');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the style class to the root element of the child component template like the following:

```
<p class="margin-5"></p>
```

And under stuff.component.scss

```
.margin-5 {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The man here. You need to do piercing CSS.
A basic one for what you actually want to do is set this stuff.component.scss to be:

```
  :host { margin: 5px; }
```

Ive posted an update on github.

Comment: This would work. But imagine that I’m using a google material component.